# Qfield form slider not working

Tags: qgis, qfield

I am just starting to use Qfield and QGIS. I have built a very nice form in QGIS which has a dial and a slider to input numeric data. When I import the project into QField the slider and dials are missing and I am left with a simple numeric data input field. Is Qfield unable to handle dials and sliders?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment Qfield does not support the Dials or sliders found in QGis. Hope someone will make a field widget for this soon!

https://qfield.org/docs/project-management/vector-layers.html#forms-and-fields